# jQuery doesn't work on content loaded with `.loaded()`

Tags: jquery

I'm working on subscribe/unsubscribe buttons, the problem I've is after it "loads" the content, jquery won't work on the loaded content.

for example if I'd click on .subscribe, the loaded content would be
`<div data-item="123" class="unsubscribe">unsubscribe</div>`
if I click on .unsubscribe it won't trigger the `$(".unsubscribe") jquery function`.

```
$(".subscribe").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().load("/index.php?do=sub&a=add&id=" + $(this).data("item"));
})

$(".unsubscribe").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().load("/index.php?do=sub&a=del&id=" + $(this).data("item"));
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're binding the event before the element is on the DOM, so the new element won't have that event attached.

You can attach it to the body and delegate it to `.unsubscribe`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.unsubscribe', function(){ 
    //your function 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use event delegation:

```
$(".subscribe").on('click', '.unsubscribe', function(){
    $(this).parent().load("/index.php?do=sub&a=del&id=" + $(this).data("item"));
})
```

When you load elements dynamically, you need to use `.on()`'s [delegated event syntax](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).